# How can I alter my code to reverse certain substrings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, slice, reverse

I am trying to move the first 2 characters in a string to the end, and the last 2 characters to the front. I then want to reverse the characters that I have moved.

For example, `bajui`. First we swap the first and last two characters, giving `uijba`, and then I want to reverse `ui` into `iu` and `ba` into `ab`, and thus the final result should be `iujab`.

Here is my current code:

```
def startToEnd(kata):
   kata = kata[-2:] + kata[2:3] + kata[:2]
   return kata
print(startToEnd("bajui"))
```

with this it will give `uijba`. How can I reverse the characters that have been moved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use string slicing to achieve this - Note this will only work as intended for strings of at least length 4.

**Code:**

```
def startToEnd(kata):
    return kata[:-3:-1] + kata[2:-2] + kata[1::-1]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> startToEnd('makam')
'makam'
>>> startToEnd("bajui")
'iujab'
```